# Endless Loop Error at Runtime

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, infinite-loop

What I'm attempting to do in this program is create a 3 dimensional array of GameObjects with the tag "Cube".

When I created the array cb, the cubes were out of order by name (each is named corresponding to its location in a composite unity 3d cube, ex: Cube000, Cube102). Therefore, I had to sort it.

I attempted to make a sort method (it's not efficient I know) and every time I run it, I get an endless loop and Unity stops responding.

The second part of the code is designed to fill the 3d array with the ordered elements of the array cb. I doubt that that's the problem but feel free to check.

Also as a side note, the main cube is hollow and thus only has 26 small cubes in it instead of 27. Anyways, why am I getting an endless loop?

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;

    public class CubeArrayLoop : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject[,,] cubes = new GameObject[3, 3, 3];


    public void Start(){
        //initialize array of Cube GameObjects
        GameObject[] cb = new GameObject[26];
        cb = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Cube");
        //sort array of Cube GameObjects
        for (int p = 1; p < cb.Length; p++) {
            GameObject first = cb [0];
            GameObject current = cb [p];
            GameObject replacer;
            if (current.name.CompareTo (first.name) < 0) {
                replacer = first;
                first = current;
                current = replacer;
                p = 1;
            }
        }

        //Debug.Log (cb);

        //fill class variable cubes with cb objects in depth, row, col order
        int count = 0;
        for (int d =0; d < 3; d++) {
            for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
                for (int c =0; c < 3; c++) {
                    if (!(d == 1 && r == 1 && c == 1)) {
                        cubes[d, r, c] = cb[count];
                        count += 1;
                    }
                    else{
                            cubes[d, r, c] = null;
                        }

                }
            }
        }

        //Debug.Log(cubes[1,2,1]);

    }

}
```

Comment: Its because of `p = 1` in your sort. You aren't correctly implementing the sort routine, why aren't you using the built-in `Array.Sort()` instead of trying to roll your own? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tf1f0bc(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Make sure you use `unity3d` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a good idea to write your own sort routine for this kind of work, especially if you don't know how to do it efficiently. .NET supplies plenty of good ways to sort things. I encourage you to learn how to implement sort routines, but do so as a project all its own.

```
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    class GameObjectComparer : IComparer<GameObject>
    {
        public int Compare(GameObject left, GameObject right)
        {
            return left.Name.CompareTo(right.Name);
        }
    }

    //sort array of Cube GameObjects
    Array.Sort(cb, new GameObjectComparer());
```